# Software to read a QR code?

Tags: software-recommendation

I saw a [QR code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_Code) reading a book, but I don't have a smart phone to decode it.

So I just took a picture of it and saved the picture to my PC. I downloaded libdecoderqr0, libdecodeqr-dev, and libdecodeqr-examples for reading it. But I don't know how to use them.

What do I do next? Or is there a nicer way to read QR codes?

Comment: The simplest way to scan a QR Code is to use one of those online services like e.g. http://qr4u.online/, https://webqr.com/

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Several options:

- **Command-line QR-code decode: `zbarimg`**

  Install the [zbarimg](https://sourceforge.net/projects/zbar/) command line application by running:

  ```bsh
  sudo apt-get install zbar-tools
  ```

  Use the program `zbarimg` provided by the package to read your QR encoded image:

  From the command line:

  ```bsh
  zbarimg "image-file-name.jpg"
  ```

  The above will display what is encoded in the image in the terminal.
- **Web-based Applications for decoding and encoding**

  You can encode and decode online at [online barcodereader.com](https://www.onlinebarcodereader.com/) and at [ZXing Decoder Online](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx).
- **Data Matrix command-line decode and encode:  `libdmtx`**

  `libdmtx` is a library for reading and writing Data Matrix 2D barcodes -- two-dimensional symbols that hold a dense pattern of data with built-in error correction.

  Install [libdmtx-utils](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libdmtx-utils) from the repository and try using the tools it provides:

  `dmtxwrite` - create Data Matrix barcodes. Simple example:

  ```bsh
  dmtxwrite  -o image.png input.txt
  ```

  This will encode text contained in `input.txt` in current directory to an image, `image.png`, in the current directory.

  `dmtxread` - scan Data Matrix barcodes. Simple example:

  ```bsh
  dmtxread image.png
  ```

  This reads the encoded `image.png` and writes the decoded messages to standard output.

  libdmtx Resources:

  - See some [tips here](http://libdmtx.wikidot.com/helpful-tips)
  - [Libdmtx home page](http://libdmtx.sourceforge.net/)
  - [Additional Resources](http://libdmtx.sourceforge.net/display.php?text=libdmtx.3)
- **Command-line QR-code encoding:  `grencode`**

  If you would like to generate QR codes, you can install `qrencode` from the repositories.

  ```bsh
  < input.txt qrencode -s 10 -o test.png
  ```

  The above will encode the information in the input.txt file in an image file called `test.png`.

  Or you can input text from the console with:

  ```bsh
  qrencode -s 10 -o ubuntu.png http://www.ubuntu.com
  ```

  The above will generate a QR encoded image called `ubuntu.png` with the URL `http://www.ubuntu.com` encoded in it.

Comment: data matrix seems way better, since it has a proper decoder and it can encode null bytes. this doesn't work: `echo -en "\x00" | qrencode -t PNG -o lol.png`

Comment: I could not get the libdecodeqr examples to output anything.  dmtx seems to be very limited regarding the size of the data; a regular SSH key wouldn't fit. (Also, libdmtx.org points to something very different nowadays.)

Comment: `zbarimg --raw qr.png > output.txt` to save it to a file. "QR-Code:" text is appended to the output if `--raw` is not enabled.

Comment: xbar-tools also contain a tool `zbarcam` with which the QR code can directly be scanned using a webcam.

Comment: Beware - the zbarimg tool will add a label `QR-Code:` to the output.  To suppress this, use the --raw option.

Comment: You can use image magick's screenshotter tool to get the image from, `import png:-|zbarimg png:- -q` would work

Comment: It would be better if each one of these solutions were a separate answer so we can vote on them separately, and so we can have discussions in the comments on each one separately.

Answer (score 38):

[ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/) recognizes several kinds of bar codes, including QR codes. If I install `zbar-tools`

```
$ sudo apt-get install zbar-tools
```

and save [that QtQR image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RMkhl.png) to a file called `askubuntu.png`, then the `zbarimg` utility finds and decodes the QR code

```
$ zbarimg askubuntu.png 
QR-Code:http://askubuntu.com
scanned 1 barcode symbols from 1 images in 0.02 seconds
```

There is also a `zbarcam` utility, which you can use to decode QR codes spotted by your web cam.

Answer (score 36):

## [QtQR](https://code.launchpad.net/qr-tools)

A graphical interface for creating and reading QR codes.

[image: QtQR]

QtQR can read QR codes from image files or from a webcam. It is able to recognise a number of specific types of QR code including web links, email addresses/messages, SMS messages and telephone numbers.

You could potentially scan the QR code from the book using a webcam. If you do this, ensure there is enough light and that you are holding the QR code flat and still. You will see a window with the webcam input on the screen. Wait until green dots appear then close the window and QtQR will tell you what was contained in the QR code.

As of Bionic (18.04), QtQR is available on Ubuntu by running:

```
sudo apt install qtqr
```

You can also install newer versions of QtQR by adding the PPA [ppa:qr-tools-developers/qr-tools-stable](https://launchpad.net/%7Eqr-tools-developers/+archive/qr-tools-stable) and installing the package `qtqr`.

Comment: Sorry, I've made the comment in the wrong browser tab. :( -- If you are going to test QtQR: https://launchpad.net/qr-tools/, there are stable and diary PPA's, you can add the daily without too much worry. Please note that if you are running Ubuntu 10.10 you need to add an extra PPA because of some dependencies not been available (zbar) There are instructions in the launchpad site. Any feddback is greatly appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qr-tools-developers/qr-tools-stable                     
sudo apt-get update                 sudo apt-get install qtqr

Comment: Here are the installation commands for QTQR sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qr-tools-developers/qr-tools-stable sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install qtqr

Comment: On ubuntu 20.04 the apt install works, but when I try to scan from webcam, it crashes. (respectively the webcam scan crashes)

Answer (score 13):

In 2020, you should use [CoBang](https://github.com/hongquan/CoBang) to scan QR code. It was written recently by me, to catch new technologies in Linux desktop.

[image: Screenshot]

How to install in Ubuntu 20.04:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ng-hong-quan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cobang
```

It doesn't support generating QR code yet. It is not high priority because there are already some websites to do, with pretty beautiful pictures.

Comment: The "paste image" feature is just what I needed to read a QR code displayed by another program.

Comment: Is there a reason this app is so large?  I've noticed that almost all the QR Code reader apps in the Mint app store weigh in around 2 Gigabytes (or more). This seems massive for such a simple program.

Answer (score 7):

Google Chrome has an extension in the Chrome Web Store called [QRreader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/bfdjglobiolninfgldchakgfldifphic).

If a QR code exists on a webpage, just right-click on it and voilà!

Comment: not anymore? link doesn't work either

Answer (score 4):

I actually wanted to be able to read these QR codes myself, so I made a little app that sits up on the system tray, you click it and it highlights all of the QR codes (or bar codes) visible on the screen and tells you what they say... Also, you can click on it and copy any of the code text to the clipboard to paste into a browser etc.  I'm using ZBar, and you can check it out here...

http://cnlohr.blogspot.com/2011/08/desktop-qr-code-reader-for-ubuntu.html

Anyone wanna help me turn it into a package?

Answer (score 2):

There was a request for a QR reader on former Ubuntu Brainstorm:

- [http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/item/15111/](https://web.archive.org/web/20130523085813/http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/item/15111/) , Internet Archive, snapshot of 2013-05-23.

Included in the comments are links to [TBarCode/X - Barcode Software](https://www.tec-it.com/en/download/tbarcodex/Default.aspx) and [DecodeCamera | SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/decodecamera/) which you might want to check out.

Comment: I've just tried DecodeCamera. But it doesn't work. The python script meet an error.

Comment: If you post the error you might be able to get help with it. The way I deal with QR codes is to just point my phone at my screen and use the app on my phone.

Comment: brainstorm.ubuntu.com has been shut down and it no longer exists.

Answer (score 2):

QTQR is not possible to install onto Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - [there are broken packages](http://code.google.com/p/qtqr/issues/detail?id=4). Instead of this you can use [this link](http://nwlinux.com/install-qtqr-in-ubuntu-10-04-lucid-using-apt-get/) to get it installed.

**Qreator** is another QR-code creator:

repository - https://launchpad.net/qreator

homepage - http://davidplanella.org/project-showcase/qreator/

**Qreator installation**

Open a terminal with Ctrl+Alt+T and type these commands:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:qreator-hackers/qreator-stable

 sudo apt-get update

 sudo apt-get install qreator
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a couple of existing utilities:

```
apt-get install scrot xclip zbar-tools
```

The copy QR and bar codes to clipboard with this one liner:

```
scrot -so /dev/stdout | zbarimg /dev/stdin | xclip
```

Make a shortcut for it:

```
mkdir -p ~/bin
tee ~/bin/qrr <<-EOF
scrot -so /dev/stdout | zbarimg /dev/stdin | xclip
EOF
chmod a+x ~/bin/qrr
```

If your `.profile` is well set up so that your local bin folder is in PATH (after next login) you can run `qrr` and select with your mouse a portion of your screen containing a QR code, the code is in your primary selection. Use `xclip -selection clipboard` to copy to clipboard.